# how can I adjust the section content to the card stop passing by the footer

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a simple page navbar, content and a footer.

In my content section I have a bunch of card, when I'm on a mobile mode or when my page has more than 6 card the last card aways pass by the footer.

can you guys help me understand what I'm doing wrong please?

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="h-screen flex flex-col bg-gray-200">
  <nav class="bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-between h-16">
    <div class="flex">
      <h4>logo</h4><a class="text-white" href="/"></a>
    </div><a class="text-white" href="/contact/">Contact</a>
  </nav>
  <section class="bg-gray-200">
    <div class="py-5 px-14 h-auto min-h-full w-screen max-w-full">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-6">
        <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-110">
          <div><img class="w-full" src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-800,height-600,resizemode-75,imgsize-3918697,pt-32,y_pad-40/67586673.jpg"></div>
          <div class="px-6 py-4"><a href="2" class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">image 1</a>
            <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">yeahhhhh</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-110">
          <div><img class="w-full" src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-800,height-600,resizemode-75,imgsize-3918697,pt-32,y_pad-40/67586673.jpg"></div>
          <div class="px-6 py-4"><a href="3" class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">image 2</a>
            <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">yeahhhhh</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-110">
          <div><img class="w-full" src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-800,height-600,resizemode-75,imgsize-3918697,pt-32,y_pad-40/67586673.jpg"></div>
          <div class="px-6 py-4"><a href="4" class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">image 3</a>
            <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">yeahhhhh</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-110">
          <div><img class="w-full" src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-800,height-600,resizemode-75,imgsize-3918697,pt-32,y_pad-40/67586673.jpg"></div>
          <div class="px-6 py-4"><a href="5" class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">image 4</a>
            <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">yeahhhhh</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="w-full fixed bottom-0 z-10 bg-gray-800 p-4">footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want your footer to always stick in the bottom section?

Comment: No, what I want is to put a space between my main content and the footer. As you can see on the example, the card is hidden behind the footer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some margin to the bottom of the section's first `div`.

```
<div>
  <nav>
    --
  </nav>
  <section>
    <div class="mb-20"> 
     ---
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="w-full fixed bottom-0 z-10 bg-gray-800 p-4">footer</footer>
</div>
```

Your footer needs some space and in the meantime, the section goes to the footer space thus the result got overflow.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="h-screen flex flex-col bg-gray-200">
  <nav class="bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-between h-16">
    <div class="flex">
      <h4>logo</h4>
      <a class="text-white" href="/"></a>
    </div>
    <a class="text-white" href="/contact/">Contact</a>
  </nav>
  <section class="bg-gray-200">
    <div class="py-5 px-14 mb-20 h-auto min-h-full w-screen max-w-full">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-6">
        <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-110">
          <div><img class="w-full" src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-800,height-600,resizemode-75,imgsize-3918697,pt-32,y_pad-40/67586673.jpg" /></div>
          <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="2" class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">image 1</a>
            <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">yeahhhhh</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-110">
          <div><img class="w-full" src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-800,height-600,resizemode-75,imgsize-3918697,pt-32,y_pad-40/67586673.jpg" /></div>
          <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="3" class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">image 2</a>
            <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">yeahhhhh</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-110">
          <div><img class="w-full" src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-800,height-600,resizemode-75,imgsize-3918697,pt-32,y_pad-40/67586673.jpg" /></div>
          <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="4" class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">image 3</a>
            <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">yeahhhhh</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg transform transition duration-500 hover:scale-110">
          <div><img class="w-full" src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-800,height-600,resizemode-75,imgsize-3918697,pt-32,y_pad-40/67586673.jpg" /></div>
          <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="5" class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">image 4</a>
            <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">yeahhhhh</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="py-2 px-10 h-10 w-full fixed bottom-0 z-10 bg-gray-800 p-4">footer</footer>
</div>
```